# What permission am I missing for AWS Glue and Development Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a development endpoint for AWS Glue.

```
{ "service":"AWSGlue",
"statusCode":400,
"errorCode":"ValidationException",
"requestId":"<here goes an UUID>",
"errorMessage":"Role arn:aws:iam::<IAM ID>:role/AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole 
      should be given assume role permissions for Glue Service.\n",
"type":"AwsServiceError" }
```

And my role has the following permissions.

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole
- AmazonAthenaFullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceRole
- CloudWatchLogsReadOnlyAccess
- AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess
- AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess

Any clues on what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was tripped up by this as well; the problem is that when you use the console to create a default glue service role it ends up creating the IAM role like this:

arn:aws:iam:::role/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole

Make note of the "service-role" in the path.

But then when choosing that role as the role you want to use in the console wizard for setting up a new dev endpoint it doesn't include the "service-role" in the path and looks for a role named like this:

arn:aws:iam:::role/AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole

I think this is just a bug in the console wizard for creating dev endpoints.  I got around it by creating a new role that doesn't have "service-role" in the path and then chose that role in the console wizard and was able to successfully create a dev endpoint.

Comment: If you follow the data lake QuickStart, don't reuse the role it creates. It creates the "/service-role" version of the role and fails when used to create a development endpoint.

Comment: This is the exact problem I encounter.

Answer (score 10):

In your trust relationship, the trust should be established with `glue.amazonaws.com`. Your role (AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole) may not have this. To confirm, go to the IAM roles console, select the IAM role: AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole and click on the `Trust Relationship` tab.

The json for this should look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example screenshot for the Trust relationship:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this AWS document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-troubleshooting-errors.html#error-assume-role-user-policy. The user (using which you have logged in to the AWS console) should have `iam:PassRole` permission; not just the IAM role (AWSGlueServiceRole-DefaultRole).

Comment: I'll try to add that. But says here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/attach-policy-iam-user.html that I can skip this if my role has full access

Comment: That statement indicates that - the user you are logging into the AWS console should have that policy attached. Because `AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess` has `iam:PassRole`.

Comment: Added AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess to the user logged in and the iam:PassRole as inline. Still does not work

Comment: Do I need to have one role for the job and another role for development endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was somehow related to an old Role that I already messed up with. Created a brand new role just for development following [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-prerequisites.html) and [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role.html), worked like a charm.